# How to save WFFM data to SQL tables

Tags: wffm

For a WFFM, I have used the `Save Action` as `Create Item`. On Submit, it creates a new item as desired.

I read that the WFFM data will be saved into these SQL tables - `FormFieldValues`, `Fact_FormSummary`, `Fact_FormEvents` and `Fact_FormStatisticsByContact` but it did not.

Those tables are empty. Is there any other option I should select in the "Save Actions", to have the data save into the tables.

In the *Sitecore.WFFM.Dependencies.config*, I changed the dataprovider from `<formsDataProvider ref="/sitecore/wffm/analytics/analyticsFormsDataProvider"/>`  to  `<formsDataProvider ref="/sitecore/wffm/analytics/sqlFormsDataProvider"/>`.

It creates the item but no data in the tables.

Using sc8.2u3.

Comment: Did you add the wffm connectionstring? And is "Save Form Data to storage" checked on the form?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the logs when you submit a form?

Comment: @Gatogordo. The "Save Form Data..." was checked by default. Is there another connection string for WFFM ??

Comment: @AhmedOkour. No. The item gets created without any errors.

Comment: @Qwerty You need to attach the WFFM database and add a connection string for it, Here are the steps : https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/82/setting_up_web_forms/installing/use_a_custom_sql_provider_to_store_form_data

Comment: How long did you wait to check the data? The form submission is not saved to the tables until after the user session has ended. You could forcefully end the session and then check again.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this following @AhmedOkour's suggestion.

1. Attach the `Sitecore_Wffm` database which will be located inside /website/data folder.
2. Open `/App_Config/Include/Sitecore.WFFM.Dependencies.config` and change the reference attribute for formsDataProvider. It should be sqlFormsDataProvider.

   *formsDataProvider ref="/sitecore/wffm/analytics/sqlFormsDataProvider"/>*
3. Open `/App_Config/Include/Sitecore.Forms.config` and check the WFFM connection string setting

   *setting name="WFM.ConnectionString" value="wfm" />*
4. Add a new connection string in /App_config/ConnectionStrings.config

*add name="wfm" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=mysite_Sitecore_wffm;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=123" />*

The connection string name should be the same as mentioned in *Sitecore.Forms.config*

5. Submit the form and you can check the data in these tables in the mysite_sitecore_wffm database - `FieldData, FormData`